# Error on including large videos with media9

Tags: beamer, errors, miktex, ghostscript, media9

I am trying to include a video of 17MB using the media9 package in a beamer presentation (I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{media9}
%\usepackage[bigfiles=true]{media9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
first page
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \includemedia[
    width=0.4\linewidth,
    height=0.3\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,
    addresource=myvideo.mp4,
    flashvars={source=myvideo.mp4}
  ]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I produce a pdf using pdflatex, it will work without a problem. If I use latex, dvi2ps, ps2pdf, however, I will get an error "TeX capacity exceeded".

I already tried increasing the main memory as recommended in the media9 package documentation and on [Problems embedding a video with multimedia an media9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66963/problems-embedding-a-video-with-multimedia-an-media9/67039#67039). This works for smaller videos, but not for the one I am trying to include.

When I activate the bigfiles option, the log states 'MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.00: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1' and no pdf output is produced.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

UPDATE:
With updated MiKTeX and media9 package v0.33, the error disappears.
New problem: Now the first page is displayed in A4 paper size (as shown in the screenshot)

[image: screenshot]

If I comment the `\includemedia` part out and keep everything else the way it is, the file is created with its two pages just fine.

Comment: Works here (I am using vanilla GPL Ghostscript 9.05, but the one shipping with MiKTeX should do as well). Which version of `media9` do you use? My `\jobname.log` says  `Package: media9 2013/09/24 v0.33 acrobat-9/X compatible media`.

Comment: Please update your MiKTeX using Update Wizard. The MiKTeX Ghostscript executable is 9.05.

Comment: Stick with the `bigfiles` option, it is the best choice for the `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` route. And update your MiKTeX installation which seems a bit rusty (GS-9.00 and probably outdated `media9` package).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. After a MiKTeX Update and an update of the movie9 package to v0.33, the pdf is produced. Now, however, if I add a page before the video with '\begin{frame} first page \end{frame}', this page will not be in presentation format but in A4 paper size.

Comment: Weird. Could you please set the page display to 'Two-Up' (View -> Page Display -> Two-Up) and add a screenshot to your question? This problem may not be related to `media9`. Comment out `\includemedia...` to see whether this is the case.

Comment: I added a screenshot and tried commenting out the `\includemedia`. Without this, the presentation looks fine.

Comment: There must be something horribly wrong with your MiKTeX installation. How do you invoke `ps2pdf`, at the command line or from within some LaTeX editor? At my end, everything is ok.

Comment: Is your `beamer` package up to date?

Comment: The beamer package is version 3.31, to my knowledge, that is the most recent. I use the Quickbuild function in TeXmaker to create the document. On a closer look, I think that the problem is connected with dvips because in that step a get a message ` 'TeX output 2013.11.12:1123' -> test.ps Page 1 may be too complex to print`

Comment: Weird. I installed texmaker-4.1. I ran latex, dvips, ps2pdf on your code one after another by pressing F2, F4, F8 (no Quickbuild). Everything is alright.

Comment: This is really weird. I tried something else: I included a smaller video, which can be included without the `bigfiles=true` option. If I generate the pdf using `\usepackage{media9}` it works fine. If I use `\usepackage[bigfiles=true]{media9}` I get the 'page may be too complex' message in the dvips step and the output has the large first page. (btw I am not the first person to come across this problem, a couple of people at my institute have the same problem)

Comment: F2, F4, F8. I get 'Process exited normally' three times. With option `bigfiles=true`. Could you e-mail me an example (with tex, dvi, ps, m9, pdf files and a small[!] video file) packaged in a ZIP file to my private address (see media9 doc)?

Comment: @AlexG: I noticed, that you uploaded a newer version meanwhile. Were the supposed bug fixed there and can this question be closed?

Comment: @Speravir: It can be closed I think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the discussed issue was caused by a bug in package `media9` which meanwhile was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug in `media9` in connection with really big files, the `bigfiles` option and the `dvips` route. An update, version 0.34, is being prepared and will be available for TeX-Live users within the next 2 days. MiKTeX may take somewhat longer.